# Pass in parameters with Angular resource service

Tags: angularjs, promise

I want to send some parameters to perform a GET on my server, and one must be in my URL (the `collabId`).

Here is my **service**:

```
/* Service */
angular.module('app').factory('CollabService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/collabs/:collabId', {collabId:'@collabId'}, {
        getCollabs: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my **controller**. I want to send the parameters in `$scope.q`, and have my `collabId` in the URL.

I've tried this, but it does not work (`400 Bad Request`):

```
/* Controller */
$scope.q = {
    "collabId": 30;
    "firstWeek": 1;
    "nbWeeks": 4;
    "year": 2015
};
CollabService.getCollabs($scope.q, {collabId: $scope.q.collabId},
    function(col) { //Print result
       console.log(col);
});
```

I think I miss something in the syntax of my query in my controller. Can you help me finding what is wrong here ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an error in the `CollabService`. Here you pass the whole `$scope.q` object:

```
CollabService.getCollabs($scope.q, {collabId: $scope.q.collabId},
    function(col) { //Print result
       console.log(col);
});
```

It should be changed to:

```
CollabService.getCollabs({collabId: $scope.q.collabId}, // <--
    function(col) { //Print result
       console.log(col);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There was a slight error in the previous solution.
I reworked it a bit & was able to get this to work for me.

```
// Factory
angular.module('app')
.factory('CollabService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/collabs/:collabId',
        {collabId: '@collabId'},
        {query: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
});


// Controller
var q = {};
q.collabId = 30;
...

// Query
CollabService.query({collabId: q.collabId}, function(promisedData) { 
     // Promised data
     console.log(promisedData);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works well, you should try :

**// Service**

```
angular.module('app')
.factory('CollabService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/collabs/:collabId', {collabId:'@collabId'});
});
```

**// Controller**

```
scope.q = {};
$scope.q.collabId = 30;
$scope.q.firstWeek = 1;
$scope.q.nbWeeks = 4;
$scope.q.year = 2015;
CollabService.get($scope.q,
    function(col) { //Print result
       console.log(col);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

This should work:

```
// Service
angular.module('app')
.factory('CollabService', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/collabs/:collabId', {collabId:'@collabId'}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            isArray: true
        }
    });
});

// Controller
var q = {};
q.collabId = 30;
q.firstWeek = 1;
q.nbWeeks = 4;
q.year = 2015;

// Get 
CollabService.get({collabId: q.collabId}, function(col) { 
     //Print result
     console.log(col);
});

// Query
CollabService.query(q, function(col) { 
     //Print result
     console.log(col);
});
```

Comment: Hello,
No it does not work.
It matchs the URL, but I get 2 Bad Request :(